# hurt or were hurt

Tags: word-usage

What sometimes happened to other children, when Hellen fought with them?

Possible Answers:

1. Other children were sometimes hurt when Hellen fought with them.
2. Other children sometimes hurt when Hellen fought with them.

Which is better, hurt or were hurt?

Comment: _Hurt_ in the intransitive would almost never be used as it is in sentence 2 by a native speaker. It is grammatically "correct," but not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the first example is better, it more clearly shows that Hellen caused the other children to be hurt.

The second sentence may also mean that other children hurt to others like in "fire hurts", though that is a little far fetched since children don't usually cause pain by touching them.

I would go with the first sentence.